# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(x\log(x))}{x\log(x)}$ without L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can someone help wit this question:
Does this limit exist?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(x\log(x))}{x\log(x)}$$

I'm not allowed to use L'Hospital's rule, or differentiate or anything like that.
I think I have to figure it out by using the epsilon-delta defintion or inequalities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one knows that
$$
\lim_{u \to 0}\frac {\sin u}u=1 \tag1
$$ and that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}x\ln x=0 
$$ then one may apply $(1)$ with $u=x\ln x$ to get, as $x \to 0^+$,

> $$
> \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac {\sin (x\ln x)}{(x\ln x)}=1. \tag2
> $$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I could do that xd

Comment: @tonytouch No problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Setting $$x\log(x)=t$$ and we have for $x$ tends to $$0^+$$ $$t$$ tends to $$0^+$$ thus we have
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$